# Foobar Error: Error compiling the code, please try again later

Tags: java, arrays, element

I am getting an error in this program for finding the missing elements in two arrays, I'm new to Java.

```
package com.google.challenges; 
public class Answer {
    public static int answer(int[] x, int[] y) { 
        for (int n : x)  {
            if (!isPresent(n, y)) {
                return n;
            }
        }
        for (int n : y) {
            if (!isPresent(n, x)) {
                return n;
            }
        }
         return 0;
     }
     private static boolean isPresent(int n, int[] b){
        for (int i : b) {
            if (n == i) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you returning 0 outside a method block? That's invalid java code

Comment: at which line you are getting compilation error? if it is with the last return 0; }  which is not part of your code what you have highlighted then this is a real compilation error as this statement is not part of any method.

Comment: As the function is returning an integer i just place a zero value return if both the if statement inside the for loop fails

Comment: this sentence "missing elements in two arrays" is confusing, do you mean the elements that are present in the first array and not present in the seconde vice-versa, or you mean the intersection of both ?

Comment: Inputs:
    (int list) x = [13, 5, 6, 2, 5]
    (int list) y = [5, 2, 5, 13]
Output:
    (int) 6

Inputs:
    (int list) x = [14, 27, 1, 4, 2, 50, 3, 1]
    (int list) y = [2, 4, -4, 3, 1, 1, 14, 27, 50]
Output:
    (int) -4
The number which is not found in both the given arrays

Comment: i am also getting same error with solution.java, solution.py is working.

Answer (score 5):

I was also getting this error message. I believe there is problem on Google's end that is not allowing Java code to compile. I have seen other reports of this issue.

Here is my evidence for the issue's lying with Google: replacing all of the code in the method `answer` with simply `return 0;` removes all doubt about whether errors in the code are causing it. In this case, the barely-altered skeleton code should successfully compile, the tests should run, and the tests should fail (unless the correct result is `0`). Instead, an error message is displayed: "Error compiling the code, please try again later."

The only solution I found was to do it in Python. When I started the challenges, I knew Java and did not know Python, but it was extremely easy to switch.

Comment: July 2018, Google still didn't fix this >:(